# CSS flexbox with single container and differently sized items

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to implement a flex box of the following scenario outlined by this positioning

```
+----+----------+----+
|   1|2>        |  <3|
+----+----------+----+
|   4|5              |
|   v|v              |
+----+               |
     |               |
+----+------+--------+
|7>         |      <6|
+-----------+--------+
```

### Explanation

- each flex item above has its order number
- number is aligned according to the end result (vertical and horizontal)
- items with number only have a predefined width
- `<>v` show dimension flexibility of an item depending on the amount of content it has;

  - `>` content will stretch to the right
  - `<` content will stretch to the left
  - `v` content will stretch down
- 1 has fixed width and height
- 1, 2 & 3 have the same height but 2 & 3 have variable width
- 4 & 5 have defined widths but different heights
- 6 & 7 have the same height but different widths
- item numbers correspond to their position in HTML
- mind that 6 and 7 are reversed in output compared to HTML

### The problem

The main problem is that all of the items are within the same flex container. Therefore I have problems wrapping them (breaking the line) at the right point i.e. items should wrap after item 3, while items 2 and 3 have to stretch over the whole line, so item 3 can display content completely to the right of itself.

[Here a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ojmghu3t/1) with inital HTML and CSS that you can work on.

### Some ideas

Maybe just for idea that crossed my mind. One could use two additional items in flexbox container by using `:before` and `:after` and giving them proper order. This way one could *simulate* some additional content to get required results.

If there were flex groups it would be much easier because one could change `flex-direction` to `column` and group several items together:1&2&3, 4&5 and 6&7 and position them in `row` within flex group with proper widths.

Comment: "*The main problem is that all of the items are within the same flex container.*", "*If there were flex groups it would be much easier*". Why can't you do that?

Comment: @Oriol: because depending on the item type not all items are being displayed and in the same order. Having them in groups would make it impossible to order beyond individual groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

This solution I've now come up with using some ideas of [@Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28419032/75642) and realising that all browsers that support flexbox also support `calc` CSS function. And based on this I was able to make flexbox container flexible and keep items within break at points I require.

Jan's answer solved my layout assuming that all item widths are relative to container, yet items #1 and #3 have fixed widths. All of the others are flexible according to layout.

I'm just adding the most important CSS that defines flex item widths on a flexible container. I'll refer to `.itemX` as a selector of flex item *X* where *X* is element number. So these selectors are just pseudo code for easier understanding. Adjust accordingly:

```
.itemAll {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.item1,
.item4 {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-basis: @FixedWidth; /* i.e. 25px */
}

.item2,
.item3 {
    flex-basis: calc((100% - @FixedWidth)/2);
}

.item5 {
    flex-basis: calc(100% - @FixedWidth);
}

.item6,
.item7 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

As we can see from my modified [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ojmghu3t/5) this actually works. Try resizing results panel width and you'll see that all flex items except #1 and #4 adjust their width according to container and always keep their layout as defined.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve the desired result by using `flex-basis`. When the items 1, 2, 3 and 4 all have a basis of 26%, the 4th item does not fit in the first row anymore. The same thing can be applied to the second row.

Then `flex-grow` can be applied to items 2, 3, 5, 6 and 7 to fill the remaining space in each row.

Finally `align-self` the 4th item, so it does not use the same height as item 5.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ojmghu3t/2/

**Update:** Of course you can also specify `px` with `flex-basis`. But then it is harder to produce a break at the correct position.

Here is the JSFiddle with fixed values for item 1 and 4: http://jsfiddle.net/ojmghu3t/4/

Comment: Well that seems ok as long as 1 and 4 can be arbitrarily sized in % of the whole width. What if I want them to be of predefined size in pixels and they should keep their size when container resizes?

Comment: Of course you can also use `px` for some elements (see updated answer). With a fixed width container this is not a problem. But when the container doesn't have a fixed width, the only solution I see to break after certain elements is using media queries or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, you can use pseudo-elements to achieve this:

```css
main::before, main::after {
    content: '';        /* Enable pseudo-elements */
    margin-right: 100%; /* Force line break */
}
main::before {
    order: 4;           /* Place it before .i4 */
}
main::after {
    order: 5;           /* Place it after .i5 */
}
```

```css
main {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}
main::before, main::after {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 100%;
}
main::before {
  order: 4;
}
main::after {
  order: 5;
}
.i2, .i3, .i5, .i6, .i7 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.i5 {
  width: 0;
}
section {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.i1, .i4 {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
.i7 {
  text-align: right;
  order: 6;
}
.i1 { order: 1; }
.i2 { order: 2; }
.i3 { order: 3; }
.i4 { order: 4; }
.i5 { order: 5; }
.i6 { order: 7; }
.i7 { order: 6; }
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="i1">1</section>
  <section class="i2">2</section>
  <section class="i3">3</section>
  <section class="i4">4</section>
  <section class="i5">This one has much more content than the rest.</section>
  <section class="i6">6</section>
  <section class="i7">7</section>
</main>
```

Comment: +1 That's a very nice trick. As long as you give pseudo elements whole width size (you've used an unusual `margin-right: 100%` but could've simply just set their `width:100%` to accomplish for the same) you break the line. The downside is though that this works in a two and 3 row scenario (which covers my layout) but fails in more than 3 row layout. Final solution though works for any layout. But it's a plausible idea. Congrats.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik True, `width` should also work, but there might be conflicts e.g. with `max-width`. If you need more than two line breaks, you could add empty elements instead of pseudo-elements. The markup shouldn't be changed for styling purposes, but it would work.

Comment: Yeah even pseudo elements could be replaced by empty elements although I don't like this idea, because in order to display something correctly, you require certain markup. So you end up with markup that some of it exists for the purpose of styling. Not really semantic... Pseudo elements aren't part of markup source which keeps it semantic.